A sort of fundamental calculus theorem
Let $u\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It is known that $$u(x)=\frac{1}{\omega_n}\int Du(y)\cdot \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^n}dy,$$ where $\omega_n$ is the surface are of the unit ball. Other identity is that $$u(x)=I_1*\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\mathcal{R}_j\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}\right),$$ where $$\mathcal{R}_jf=\frac{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{\pi^{(n+1)/2}}\int f(y)\frac{x_j-y_j}{|x-y|^{n+1}}dy=C_n\int f(y)\frac{x_j-y_j}{|x-y|^{n+1}}dy,$$ is the $j$-th component of the Riesz transform and $$I_s(x)=\frac{1}{\gamma_s|x|^{n-2}},$$ is the Riesz kernel, with $$\gamma_s=\frac{\pi^{n/2}\Gamma(s/2)}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}.$$ Both seems to be the same result but with different expressions, but they are proved in different ways, and i waswondering if I could pass from one to the another. My work so far: $$I_1*\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\mathcal{R}_j\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}\right)=I_1*\left(\sum_{j=1}^nC_n\int D_jf(y)\frac{x_j-y_j}{|x-y|^{n+1}}dy\right)=I_1*\left(C_n\int Df(y)\frac{x-y}{|x-y|^{n+1}}dy\right)=\frac{C_n}{\gamma_1}\int\frac{\int Df(y)\frac{x-y}{|x-y|^{n+1}}dy}{|x-z|^{n-1}}dz.$$ However, i don't know how to continue from here. Any help will be very appreciated
